# Incompatible pointer types warning when printing function pointers

Tags: arrays, c, function-pointers, declaration, function-call

I am trying to create an array of function pointers, so that I can print out output from the functions by using the pointers. (For an exercise from the Effective C book.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int a(void) { return 1; }
int b(void) { return 2; }
int c(void) { return 3; }

int main(void)
{

    int(*func_arr)[3] = {&a, &b, &c};
    printf("%d\n", (*func_arr)[0]);
}
```

However, when I compile it, I get the warnings

```
starting.c:10:26: warning: incompatible pointer types initializing 'int (*)[3]' with an expression of type
      'int (*)(void)' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    int(*func_arr)[3] = {&a, &b, &c};
                         ^~
starting.c:10:30: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer
    int(*func_arr)[3] = {&a, &b, &c};
                             ^~
```

And, when I run the program, I get an output of -443987883, while it should just be 1.

Does anyone know the solution for this? Thank you!

Comment: `int(*func_arr)[3]` isn't what you think it is.

Comment: `typedef` can make using function pointers easier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This declaration

```
int(*func_arr)[3] = {&a, &b, &c};
```

declares a pointer to the array type `int[3]`.

So there is declared a scalar object of a pointer type that you are trying to initialize using a brace enclosed list of initializers with more than one initializer of an incompatible pointer type.

Instead you need to write

```
int ( *func_arr[3] )( void ) = { a, b, c };
```

The function designators used as initializers are implicitly converted to pointers to the functions.
So there is no need to write as for example `&a` though such an expression is also valid to be used as an initializer.

To simplify the array declaration you could introduce a typeded name for the function pointer type.

For example

```
typedef int ( *FnPtr )( void );
```

Now the array declaration can look the following way

```
FnPtr func_arr[3] = { a, b, c };
```

And to output results of function calls you need to write calls of `printf` like

```
printf("%d\n", func_arr[0]() );
```

Comment: Fun fact: it's not just in initializers that function designators are automatically converted to function pointers.  Functions are much like arrays, in that expressions of function type are automatically converted to pointers in almost every context in which they appear (the exceptions being two of those that apply to arrays: as operands to `sizeof` and unary `&`).  The function call operator, `()`, is defined as an operator on function *pointers*.

Comment: Thank you! Also, why would you omit the `*` before `func_arr[0]` in the `printf` statement?

Comment: @laffytaffy You may use a pointer to function in the postfix expression of a function call.